# Avoid narrowing to literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create wrappers for primitive types with possible nullable values if specified. But encountered a problem: TS automatically narrows type to provided value. It can be bypassed by manual type specification in generic, but it looks kind of ugly for the main use case.

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    constructor(
        public value: T
    ) { }
}

class StringWrapper<T extends string | null = string> extends Wrapper<T> {

}

new Wrapper(`a`); // Wrapper<string> - Perfect
new StringWrapper(`a`); // StringWrapper<'a'> - Too narrowed
new StringWrapper<string>(`a`); // StringWrapper<string> - Ugly
```

Is there are possibility to avoid narrowing to literal and make such cases possible?

```
type TClock = `Tic` | `Tac`;

new StringWrapper(1); // TS error 
new StringWrapper(`a`); // StringWrapper<string> 
new StringWrapper<TClock>(`Tic`); // StringWrapper<TClock>
new StringWrapper<TClock | null>(null); // StringWrapper<TClock | null>
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NneVxw) meet your needs? (Please test against use cases you care about.) If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [It's okay to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) but it should be posted as an answer and not as an edit to the question.  And I was planning to do this myself, along with an explanation and not just code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) that includes `string`, like `T extends string | null` serves as a hint to the compiler that it should infer a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for `T` if possible.  This is intended behavior, as implemented and described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

So if you want to avoid such narrowing, you can't constrain `T` to `string | null`. One alternative approach is not to constrain `T` at all, but anywhere you were using a value of type `T`, you use a value of the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & (string | null)`.  So any part of `T` that isn't assignable to `string | null` will be removed (e.g., `(number) & (string | null)` reduces to `never`).  This has much the same effect as a constraint, without the inference behavior:

```
class StringWrapper<T,> extends Wrapper<T & (string | null)> { }
```

So now everything behaves as you wanted in terms of inference:

```
type TClock = `Tic` | `Tac`;
new StringWrapper(`a`); // StringWrapper<string> 
new StringWrapper<TClock>(`Tic`); // StringWrapper<TClock>
new StringWrapper<TClock | null>(null); // StringWrapper<TClock | null>
```

but the compiler still rejects constructor arguments which would have violated your intended constraint:

```
new StringWrapper(3) // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8AVAfNA3gFDQnTAD2AdhAC7wCuwN58AFMaZ0vQEYgCWwaADcwIeqgBc0LBxIBKAtAC+hVYVCQYAZTr9KAcwTI0mLABo8qAB41UlACYxjKdNmgAyaK1rx9B6AAfaEp6EBB5PHwVQkJKVAB3OERXNgADMDT5AG5oAHo85JM3X388AFpoAAV0ADNUJjjE6F0-QxdTVgys3IKWvXaU0wwAcjARiplychCweHhyBNQHJqTW-w6SgYMcLsyc-ML1weLMUsNJgFUDEABPWPi17c22AGZFPvQF+FiaW7QZABhEDkYAAa2gAF5oGksII0kEYVgwMA0tlVv02kYhug9j1DpiNjizts8BjjtjTthgaCwbtYfCDn0KS9qSDwThyc9iWzaYjQuFdgKIr0jtyqVgaeD+WEQJzCEA)